# How can I align 6 <div> horizontally in one HTML page,with each <div> width equal to that of browser width?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Right now ,
I have achieved this by keeping my body width=12000px;
and each div width=2000px;

But i want to change div width dynamically with the browser width,to have standard view on any screen size.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting something like that.

Comment: I'm sorry if I did something wrong.But I really need to know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
div.horisontal { height: 100px; float: left }
```

JS (load jquery before, you will need it anyway):

```
$(function(){
    var bw = $(window).width();
    $('div.horisontal').width(bw);
})
$(window).resize(function(){
    var bw = $(window).width();
    $('div.horisontal').width(bw);
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="horisontal">div1</div>
<div class="horisontal">div2</div>
<div class="horisontal">div3</div>
<div class="horisontal">div4</div>
<div class="horisontal">div5</div>
<div class="horisontal">div6</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question here is a good guide.

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/

Comment: Please do not post a link as your answer.  SO answers should be fully "self-contained" with external links only as a reference.